# Xamarin.Forms: How to make the iOS status bar background opaque black?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a ContentPage with a WebView in a NavigationPage with no navigation bar (`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`).

The problem: the status bar on iOS is always transparent, and content can be seen through it. I want to avoid this, I want an opaque / solid black status bar with white text.

I thought about simply having a coloured rectangle below the status bar with a height of 20 pt, but then how to ensure it has the correct size for iPhone X-type phones, which is 44 pt? (iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR).

- `NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor` and `BarTextColor` doesn't seem to make a difference when the navigation bar is hidden.
- `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` is deprecated.
- Setting `UIStatusBarStyle` with
  `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance == false` can change the
  colour of the text, but not the background: the background is always
  transparent.
- I haven't found an answer in other Stack Overflow questions (or anywhere else for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a coloured rectangle below the status bar is correct.

In a custom page renderer for the page (here called `MyPage`), create a view/subview (`UIView`) with a black background that covers up the status bar (i.e. is beneath it, providing a background for it). As far as I understand, since iOS 7, the status bar never has a background and is always translucent.

```
using MyApp;
using MyApp.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(MyPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            UIView statusBarCoverView = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame);
            statusBarCoverView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
            View.AddSubview(statusBarCoverView);
        }
    }
}
```

Xamarin.Forms NavigationPage will insist on making the status bar text black even with the black background view in place if the previous background was bright, even with `BarBackgroundColor` and `BarTextColor` set.

The only way to change this I've found so far is to set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `false` in `Info.plist`, which results in the status bar text to always be white in the entire app:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Not ideal, but I haven't found out how to set it otherwise. `UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle`, `PreferredStatusBarStyle` or `SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` don't seem to work. I suspect this is because the page is a child controller of the NavigationPage controller.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode I was able to achieve this without using code.  First, make sure you are using a Navigation Controller.  Then you click on the top Nav bar in that controller and change the Style to "Black", the Bar Tint to Black Color, and the Tint (near the bottom) to White Color.  Then it will automatically fill in stuff as expected.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the question was specifically about Xamarin.Forms and a page that has no navigation bar visible.

Comment: Oops, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make this page not show navigation bar in Xamarin.Forms,

add this page not the root of Navigation Page.

I suggest that when you push to this WebView page ,not use Navigation page, just do that.

```
 Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NextPage());
```

Not use `Navigation.PushAsync(new NextPage());`

**More info:**

If Xamarin.Forms's method can not work , you can try native ios method to do that.

Setting `UIStatusBarStyle` with `UIBarStyleBlack`

Setting `navigationBar.translucent` with `NO`

**translucent** :
A Boolean value indicating whether the navigation bar is translucent (YES) or not (NO).

Comment: The question is not about the navigation bar, and the ContentPage with a WebView is the startup page. Can you elaborate on the native iOS method? I do not see why I would want to set a background image when I want opaque black, or where in the lifetime of the app/page to call it.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your prolem.That will be helpful.Sometimes Forms can not take care of all platforms.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where to set `navigationBar.translucent` so that Xamarin.Forms doesn't override it? Would it require a custom renderer for the ContentPage?

Comment: Yes,it require a custom renderer for ContentPage .If be helpful ,can mark to  help others.

Comment: Ok, If you think my answer is useful .You can mark it be right.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer wasn't very helpful, as I was asking about a page with the navigation bar hidden. I've managed to find a solution, see my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I mistaked question with navigation bar.Glad you have solved this problem!^.^